# Sidetiq testing with TimeCop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, timecop, sidetiq

I'm trying to write some test for my Sidekiq jobs that use Sidetiq and I can't seem to get it to work. I've found an issue on the sidetiq repo dealing with this problem but no one has answered it so I thought I could bring it to stackoverflow to get some answers and clarity.

Here is the link to the issue:https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/issues/72

and here is the code that won't seem to work:

`spec.rb`

```
# sat 1st feb
Timecop.travel Time.local(2014, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1) do
  sign_up_and_onboard user[:email], user[:password]

 # sunday 2nd feb, 8pm
  Timecop.travel Time.local(2014, 2, 2, 20, 1, 1) do
    puts 'should have fired'
  end
end
```

`worker.rb`

```
recurrence { weekly.day(:sunday).hour_of_day(8) }

def perform
    puts 'test'
end
```

Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears - from the code you've posted - as if nothing is actually firing your workers. It's not clear what your signup_and_onboard method does - perhaps that is firing them.

I'd recommend using sidekiq/testing (see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing), and then firing your workers through the Sidetiq handler, using something like:

```
Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
  expect(
    Sidetiq::Handler.new.dispatch(MyWorker, Time.now)
  ).to be_truthy
end
```

inside your Timecop block.

This is the best way I could find from examining the Sidetiq codebase to fire the workers through enough of the Sidetiq stack to get the behaviour I wanted to see in a test.